# how to Connect/Pair LE device with mobile in react native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am facing some problem to connect LE Device to the mobile in react native and i have used  react-native-ble-plx for that. So the enable and disable is working properly but i can't connect to that particular device.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask] good questions. What is your exact problem? react-native-ble-plx offers a [documentation](https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/), did you take a look at it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.